# Formula for product of sums of pairs of coprime divisors of $n$.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, divisor-counting-function, coprime

Can we develop a formula for

$$
r(n)=\prod_{
\begin{array}{c}
x,y\mid n \\
(x,y)=1
\end{array}}
(x+y)
$$

In words this is the product of sums of all coprime pairs of divisors of $n$.

For example
$$r(12)=(1+2)(1+3)(1+4)(1+6)(1+12)(2+3)(3+4)=191100$$

There is some information on the number of coprime pairs of divisors ([A063647](https://oeis.org/A063647)).

In answer to the comment, this problem comes from wanting to know whether a certain function of $n$ divides at least one of the $(x+y)$ terms. This is true iff the function divides $r(n)$. I have no idea if a nice form exists, but I would certainly accept a form in terms of the prime factorization of $n$.

Comment: Where did this problem come from and/or do you have a reason to believe there's a nice closed form expression for this?

Comment: I mean you can write the prime factorization of $n$ and get an expression.

Comment: "This is true iff the function divides r(n)." That's not true in general. f(n) = n+1 comes to mind...

Comment: True @TodorMarkov I realized this recently.

Comment: However I may be able to show that my $f(n)$ is a prime...